# TypeScript React Js, Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this functions and this types:

> type ClickHandler = (tag: ITag) => void;
>
> type ShowHideDropItem = (tag: ITag) => void;

my tsx:

```
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState<ITag[]>(SideBarTags);

  const clickHandler: ClickHandler = (tag) => () => {
    showHideDropItem(tag);
  };

  const showHideDropItem: ShowHideDropItem = (tag) => {
    setMenuItems((items) =>
      items.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        Active:
          item.Name === tag.Name ? (tag.Active === true ? false : true) : false,
      }))
    );
  };
```

but i got this error on my onClick:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event:
>   MouseEvent) => void) | undefined'.  TS2322

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`clickHandler` is a *curried* function (a function that returns a function). Consider including it in your type:

```
type ClickHandler = (tag: ITag) => (e: React.MouseEvent) => void;
```

**Note**: The need of `e` (`event`) argument depends if you want to use it in your function or not.

**Edit**: Your function would look like:

```
const clickHandler: ClickHandler = (tag) => (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   showHideDropItem(tag);
};
```

Comment: Hello thanks what should i change in my type to be able to use my event.preventdefault in my function?

Comment: @gabriel Just remember to import `MouseEvent` from 'react' or simply use `React.MouseEvent`. Then, use `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: could you show me how my type and my onclick would look by sending the event?

I tested and couldn't :(

Comment: @gabriel Updated my answer

Comment: i got this error on my e.prevent : Object is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2532

Comment: @gabriel Remove the question mark `?` after e `(e: React...)`

Comment: I didn't remove it was waiting for the minimum time to mark it, thank alot for help @kind user